# React native get a specific element value from state array

Tags: arrays, react-native

I am new to React-Native i am building a sample app, But i ha d small problem with this.state.array , I want a particular element value from array 
my array is

```````````````````````````````````````````
this.state.userDetail: [
  Object {
    "creation_Date": "2019-10-22T06:34:52.000Z",
    "mobile": 9985849955,
    "name": "siva",
    "password": "123456",
    "picture_url": "5.jpg",
    "role": "",
    "user_id": 1,
  },
]

````````````````````````````````````````
In the above array i want user_id value ,
i tried different methods like

```````````````````````````

this.setState({ user_id: this.state.user_Details.user_id })

const item_id = this.state.user_Details.map((item) => { item.user_id });

var item_id = this.state.user_Details.filter(userDetails => {  return userDetails[7]; })
 ``````````````````````````````````````````



but nothing will work i want only user_id value to update the users table , So please any help ..
```````````````````````````````````````````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to extract the user_id SPECIFICALLY from this example:

```
[
  {
    "creation_Date": "2019-10-22T06:34:52.000Z",
    "mobile": 9985849955,
    "name": "siva",
    "password": "123456",
    "picture_url": "5.jpg",
    "role": "",
    "user_id": 1,
  },
]
```

and assuming this data is in your `this.state.userDetail` property.
The only thing you need is:

```
this.state.userDetail[0].user_id
```

Why this might not be working for you:

```
this.state.userDetail: [
  Object { /// What's Object?
```

And if you are trying to parse more than 1 entry in the array unlike your example, you first need to select a certain entry with a 'for' loop or a .map() function.

Comment: I am using React-Native There is only one array , when i am  using your method getting error like

`undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.userDetail[0]')
* screens\EditMobileScreen.js:77:52 in sendOTP
* screens\EditMobileScreen.js:118:24 in <unknown>
- node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:37:14 in tryCallOne
- node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:123:25 in <unknown>
- ... 8 more stack frames from framework internals`

Comment: Can you give the code snippet for your app? Have you done this.setState({userDetail: <your array>})

Comment: yes , i got this array from another component by using 

onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('EditMobile', { edit_Details })}

` componentDidMount() {

        this.setState({ user_Details: this.props.navigation.getParam('edit_Details') })
}`

getting the array correctly but unable to get the user_id

Comment: This is much more complex than in your initial question. You need to make sure that you set up react-navigation properly. If yes, you also need to check that when you are running this.state.edit_Details, that this.setState has completed. Use the debugging tool to check what is happening with the state. For the example you gave initially, both my answer and @Lenoarod one are correct.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.Its working fine as expected. Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to get  one index user id, so I give the following code:

```
// define it in the constructor, and it may have more than one items
this.state.userDetail: [
   {
    "creation_Date": "2019-10-22T06:34:52.000Z",
    "mobile": 9985849955,
    "name": "siva",
    "password": "123456",
    "picture_url": "5.jpg",
    "role": "",
    "user_id": 1,
  },
]

// do not directly assign use this.state.x
let copyUserDetails = {...this.this.state.user_Details}
let userIdsArray = copyUserDetail.map((item) => { return item.user_id });
let itemId = userIdsArray[0]
console.log("the first user Id is",itemId)
// if you only want to the user_id, you can directly copyUserDetails[0].user_id
let userId = copyUserDetails[0].user_id
console.log("the first user Id is  ==> ",userId)
this.setState({ user_id: itemID })


// the filter is accordng some condtion to return a new arry
let  itemFilterArray = copyUserDetails.filter((element,i) => { 
  // filter the item which match some condition, for example the uerId not equal 
  //0 
  if(element.user_id !== 0){
       return element
    }
})
```

according to your require, I give the following code:

```
//if you do not have many userInfo
constructor(props){
   super(props)
   this.state= {
   user_Details: {
    "creation_Date": "2019-10-22T06:34:52.000Z",
    "mobile": 9985849955,
    "name": "siva",
    "password": "123456",
    "picture_url": "5.jpg",
    "role": "",
    "user_id": 1,
    }
  }

  // somewhere you want the userId
  getUserId = () => {
      return this.state.user_Details.user_id
   }





}
//if you have many userinfo
constructor(props){
   super(props)
   this.state= {
   user_Details: [{
    "creation_Date": "2019-10-22T06:34:52.000Z",
    "mobile": 9985849955,
    "name": "siva",
    "password": "123456",
    "picture_url": "5.jpg",
    "role": "",
    "user_id": 1,
    }]
  }

  // somewhere you want the some index userId
  getUserId = (index) => {
     // do not directly assign use this.state.x
     let copyUserDetails = {...this.this.state.user_Details}
     return copyUserDetails[index].user_id
   }
   //somwhere you want all the userId
  getUserId = () => {
      // do not directly assign use this.state.x
     let copyUserDetails = {...this.this.state.user_Details}
     let userIdArray = copyUserDetail.map((item) => { return item.user_id });
     return userIdArray
   }
}
```

and I suggest you can read the api about [json](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/JSON) and [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Comment: Sir thank you for the response , Your answer is not working , getting itemId undefined when i check it with console.log(itemId),

and a small error in the code 

let itemId = userIdsArray[7]
this.setState({ user_id: itemID })


if you have any better suggestion tell me sir 
where itemID => itemId

Comment: @ Sivasankar chimata , Hi，`this.state.userDetail` in the the example code only has one item, so `the userIdsArray[7]` is undefined. you should use 0 or add data to the source data

Comment: `let userDetails = this.state.user_Details`


        `let userIdsArray = userDetails.map((item) => { return item.user_id });`

        `let itemId = userIdsArray[4]`

        `this.setState({ user_id: itemId })`

      `  console.log(' sendOTP user_id:=> ', itemId)`


this is my code user_Details have values

Comment: @Sivasankar chimata, I update the answer, I guess you only want to get the userId, you can directly use second way

Comment: thank you for the response sir, but i tried your filter method also its showing  empty  array .
If you have time please use this array and try it 

`this.state.userDetail: [
   {
    "creation_Date": "2019-10-22T06:34:52.000Z",
    "mobile": 9985849955,
    "name": "siva",
    "password": "123456",
    "picture_url": "5.jpg",
    "role": "",
    "user_id": 1,
  },
]`

Comment: @ Sivasankar chimata， this is because the array does not have the index(7) element.so the empty is correct. I will explain it in the answer

Comment: Sir i don't want total array i just need user_id value only for React-Native app 

`user_id = this.state.user_Details.user_id`

Comment: @ Sivasankar climate,hi,I think you must have a base idea for array and JSON, then according to your condition, choose the one solution.

Comment: Thank you  Lenoarod and  Dmitriorohhov  for your valuable response and time. you both helped me a lot.